# Retrieve SPList URL programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Lets say I have a SharePoint List provided on URL http://webapp:1234/Lists/TestList.

In code, I have access to the corresponding SPList-Instance only. How can I get the URL of this `SPList`-Instance programmatically?

The SPList class is missing an URL property or something like that...

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the url, you might really want the url of the default view of the list: `mylist.DefaultView.Url`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to combine the list's root folder URL with the web URL. Root folder URL can be accessed via [`SPFolder.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.url.aspx) and web's absolute URL via [`SPWeb.Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.url.aspx). Providing you have a `list` it will be something like `list.ParentWeb.Url + list.RootFolder.Url`.

However, read the documentation, try it and fix things like proper slashes etc. You might also need to figure out the hostname portion of the URL from the parent `SPWebApplication` object. Note that the site may be accessible via multiple hostnames because of alternate access mappings.

Also, [`SPUtility.GetFullUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getfullurl.aspx) may come in handy to convert a server-relative URL into a full URL.

Comment: A slightly shorter version would be to simply use `list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl` property value.

Answer (score 1):

you can try This

```
SPList newlist = web.Lists(Web.Url + "Lists/listname");
```

Comment: For Libraries Remove "Lists/"

Comment: @GeorgeNorberg ya,but is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

this fits for me:

```
string sitecol= SPContext.Current.Site.Url.ToString();

string list= myList.DefaultView.Url.ToString();

string listlink = sitecol + "/" + list;
```